# Как скомпилировать php на ubuntu и заставить работать с apache?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache

Может ли работать PHP 5.6 на Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS ?
Я уже пробовал всё, что нашел в гугле, например:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
```

После ввода команды apt-get install php5.6, такое:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'
```

, т.к. ничего не получилось я решил действовать след. инструкции:

[image]

всё получилось, но как его поставить под apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё попробуй "apt-get install php56"  если не пробовал, если такого пакета нет в репозитории, то компилируй php56 как описал ниже.

**Если что я описал суть процесса на archlinux так как пользуюсь им, поэтому пути могут отличаться, в частности у меня php ставиться в "usr/local/php56" поэтому как это будет у тебя я точно не знаю, но суть подключения php к апачу думаю должна быть ясна**

Тебе нужен модуль для apache он при компиляции php создается, тебе надо перекомпилировать php c добавлением параметра

```
--with-apxs2='путь до apxs'
```

или так

```
--with-apxs='путь до apxs'
```

"apxs - APache eXtenSion tool" может иметь названия "apxs" и "apxs2" так что посмотри как он называется у тебя в дистрибутиве, если его нет, установи(если апач из репозитория обычно он имеется и можно через команду "which apxs(2)" в консоли посмотреть путь, если не через репозиторий то ищи в папке апача, по дефолту "usr/local/apache(2)/bin".

Далее в файле "etc/httpd/httpd.conf"(папка апача у меня везде называется "httpd", у тебя может быть по другому) найти блок где подгружаются модули(он в самом начале) и вписать модуль php56(обязательно после строки "LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so")

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp56.so
```

А так же подключить конфиг(он тоже должен создаться при компиляции), они инклюдятся где то в самом конце, там в конец всех подключений вставь строчку

```
Include conf/extra/php56_module.conf
```

Вообщем суть подключить библиотеку php в конфиге апача и конфиг самого php. По путям смотри где у тебя что лежит.
После этого включаешь апач, и проверяй через

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```